# Exception decrypting secret key - pgp Decryption - c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, encryption, bouncycastle, pgp

I am trying to decrypt multiple pgp files and I copied decryption code from [here](http://www.mindfiresolutions.com/PGP-Encryption--Decryption-in-C-1994.php#top). when I execute my application it gives me an exception `Exception decrypting secret key`, I looked into this already asked [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13679204/exception-on-decrypting-file-using-bouncycastle-pgp) and added that method in my `in PgpEncryptionKeys` class. but still getting the same exception.

Comment: That's very unfortunate. What's your question?

Comment: my question is that how can I fix this exception

Comment: "don't forget to modify the constructor as such: public PgpEncryptionKeys(string publicKeyPath, string privateKeyPath, string passPhrase, bool toEncrypt)"

Comment: I tried but when I call this class what will I put in that field ?

Comment: You didn't write what kind of an error you are getting, it's impossible to help you. I have a sample code which I recently created though, I can share with you if you like.

Comment: I used didisoft, a third party control to decrypt files, it worked (y)